# How to fixed error: "You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {}", in my React-Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error:I have error: 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

App.js(components):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchData } from '../actions';
import TableData from "./TableData";
import TableSearch from "./TableSearch";

export function searchFilter (search, data) {                                               
  return data.filter(n => n.term.toLowerCase().includes(search));
}


export const days = ["23-08-2019", "24-08-2019", "25-08-2019"];        

class Root extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchData(this.props.day);
  }

  render() {
    const { search, shift, data, filteredData, onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData } = this.props;

   return (
      <div>
        <TableSearch value={search}
          onChange={(e) => onSetSearch(e.target.value)} 
          onSearch={() => onFilter()} />

        {days && days.map((day, i) => (
          <button key={day} 
            onClick={() => onFetchData(day)}
            className={i === day ? "active" : ""}>{day}</button>
        ))}
        <br />
        {data && Object.keys(data).map(n => (
          <button data-shift={n}
            onClick={(e) => onFilter({ shift: e.target.dataset.shift })}
            className={n === shift ? "active" : ""}>{n} shift</button>
        ))}

        {data && <TableData data={filteredData} /> }

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export const ConnectedRoot = connect(             
  (state) => state,
  (dispatch) => ({
    onFilter: (args) => dispatch({ type: 'RUN_FILTER', ...args }),
    onSetSearch: (search) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_SEARCH', search }),
    onFetchData: (day) => dispatch(fetchData(day))
  })
);



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Onv.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0b9i.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look's like you missed on applying connect to the Root component

```
export const ConnectedRoot = connect(             
  (state) => state,
  (dispatch) => ({
    onFilter: (args) => dispatch({ type: 'RUN_FILTER', ...args }),
    onSetSearch: (search) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_SEARCH', search }),
    onFetchData: (day) => dispatch(fetchData(day))
  })
)(Root);
```

Comment: thunks, but now I have new problem: 
http://i.piccy.info/i9/6899cf91d5cc2bb59e5459f0e181f795/1573120761/40855/1334636/Screenshot_20.jpg
can you to advise something?

Comment: State is only present inside components. It looks like you are trying to use `this.state` inside an action. What you wanna do here use the `day` variable instead of the this.state.day

Comment: so where and what do i need to change?

Comment: You would have to change the one in your `response = await`. You have a `this.state.day` in the URL of the Axios call.

Comment: can you help me do this? because I really don't know how to do it. I just started learning redux. Can you fix it in this sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-ant-design-filter-table-column-with-slider-37pxf

Comment: `const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/${days[day]}`
    );` This is what I was talking about. `${days[day]} ` is the change

Comment: then how do i write this file:
```import { days } from "../components/app";
export function fetchData (day) {                                                   
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_START', day });
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/${days[this.state.day]}`);
    const data = (await response.json()).body;

    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_END', data });
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_SHIFT', data });
  }
} ``` ?

Comment: `import { days } from "../components/app"; export function fetchData (day) { return async (dispatch) => { dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_START', day }); const response = await fetch(`https://api.iev.aero/api/flights/${days[day]}`); const data = (await response.json()).body; dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_END', data }); dispatch({ type: 'SET_SHIFT', data }); } }`

Comment: inserted the code into the file and such an error:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/555a5ea24fca3c75dc7cba7c994ff68e/1573128291/35952/1334636/Screenshot_21.jpg

Comment: import { days } from "../components/app"; export function fetchData (day) { return async (dispatch) => { dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_START', day }); const response = await fetch(\`api.iev.aero/api/flights/${days[day]}\`); const data = (await response.json()).body; dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_END', data }); dispatch({ type: 'SET_SHIFT', data }); } }

Comment: No problem! Best of luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the (Root) to the end of connect in the ConnectedRoot function

```
export const ConnectedRoot = connect(             
  (state) => state,
  (dispatch) => ({
    onFilter: (args) => dispatch({ type: 'RUN_FILTER', ...args }),
    onSetSearch: (search) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_SEARCH', search }),
    onFetchData: (day) => dispatch(fetchData(day))
  })
)(Root);
```